# How to fix line breaks?

Tags: powershell

I'm kind of new to PowerShell and I need to fix a bank statement file. The problem is that this file has a CNAB 240 standard, however, it comes with a line break, so we have to fix it manually.

I have a script that makes this correction, however, I can't make it run alone because I need to use CMD to run PowerShell.
My idea is to use this script in the task manager to look for the .txt file and fix it, does anyone have any ideas?

Follow the script:

```
if ($args.count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Error "Please enter a file to read"
    return
}

$file = $args[0]

if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($file))
{
    Write-Error "File not found: $file"
    return
}

$expectedsize = 240
$lastSize = 0

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($file))
{
    if ($line.length -gt 0)
    {
        if (!($row.length -eq $expectedsize) -And (($row.length + $lastSize) -eq $expectedsize))
        {
            Write-Host -NoNewLine $linha
            $lastSize += $line.length
        }
        else
        {
            if ($lastSize -gt 0)
            {
                Write-Host
            }
            Write-Host -NoNewLine $linha
            $lastSize = $line.length
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host
    }
}
```

The script above makes the normal correction of the file, however, I am not able to make it follow the steps below:

- Browse the txt file
- Validate that it does not have the 240 positions in each line
- And then make the correction

Comment: does your code work on the damaged file? if so ... what is your Question? if not ... what is your actual Question?

Comment: Sounds like he wants to automate the script to have it run and correct the files without manual intervention.  Is that correct Lucas?

Comment: Hi guys, that's right Daniel.
I can't get it to run automatically I need some ideas to get this done

Comment: You could use a scheduled task and / or [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0) Lucas

Comment: Santiago, sobre agendar eu sei o processo, o problema é que nao estou conseguindo fazer com que o script busque arquivo >> Valide que não tem o 240 posições e depois corrija

Comment: Eu nao falo Portugues :( sorry only Spanish

Comment: Santiago, sorry, I ended up answering in Portuguese, about scheduling I know the process, the problem is that I can't make the script search for a file >> Validate that it doesn't have 240 positions and then correct it

Comment: All right, you should definitely [add this information to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71943755/edit) so it's clear where you need help and others can see it

Comment: correction made, Santiago